# Live Search JSON Data Using Ajax jQuery not work?

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

My code isn't working. This is my file.
When it works it's not showing the list and throws error in Json file.I don't know why??
**You can will see  error in the Console**

***It's my Json file inner:*** **data.json**

```html
[
    {
      "name":"Angel Lewis",
      "image": "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_200_200/p/3/000/0d4/2f7/07a3d35.jpg",
      "location":"Seattle, WA"
    },
    { ...
      },
      ......
    ]
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
 $('#search').keyup(function(){
  $('#result').html('');
  $('#state').val('');
  var searchField = $('#search').val();
  var expression = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
  $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
   $.each(data, function(key, value){
    if (value.name.search(expression) != -1 || value.location.search(expression) != -1)
    {
     $('#result').append('<li class="list-group-item link-class"><img src="'+value.image+'" height="40" width="40" class="img-thumbnail" /> '+value.name+' | <span class="text-muted">'+value.location+'</span></li>');
    }
   });   
  });
 });

 $('#result').on('click', 'li', function() {
  var click_text = $(this).text().split('|');
  $('#search').val($.trim(click_text[0]));
  $("#result").html('');
 });
});
```

[image: Console]

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to run Your code on any server like [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html) because `XMLHttpRequest()` not works on `file:///` protocols. Therefore `$.ajax` or `$.getJSON` functions also will not work

Just try to run your files on `http://` or `https://` protocols